# Splitting, enriching and putting back together

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a message carrying XML (an order) containing multiple homogenous nodes (think a list of products) in addition to other info (think address, customer details, etc.). I have to enrich each 'product' with details provided by another external service and return the same complete XML 'order' message with enriched 'products'.

I came up with this sequence of steps:

1. Split the original XML with xpath to separate messages (also keeping the original message)
2. Enrich split messages with additional data
3. Put enriched parts back into the original message by replacing old elements.

I was trying to use multicast by sending original message to endpoint where splitting and enriching is done and to aggregation endpoint where original message and split-enriched messages are aggregates and then passed to processor which is responsible for combining these parts back to single xml file. But I couldn't get the desired effect...

What would be the correct and nice way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to split the message into separate messages?  Can you enrich the original message in stages without the scatter/gather approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Splitter EIP in Camel can aggregate messages back (as a Composed Message Processor EIP).
http://camel.apache.org/splitter

See this video which demonstrates such a use-case
http://davsclaus.blogspot.com/2011/09/video-using-splitter-eip-and-aggregate.html

Comment: We do use aggregation, but we still need original message at the aggregation point. This is where we run into trouble.

Comment: You can store the original message as a property on the exchange, and then get that in the AggregationStrategy.

Comment: I've used this approach to populate the oldExchange with the original message. Seems a shame that the oldExchange can't have the original message as it's body, as default,  in a split component, much like the enrich component behaves, I think?